# Find the general term of the sequence.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

The given sequence is : $2\frac{1}{2}, 1\frac{7}{13}, 1\frac{1}{9}, \frac{20}{23}, ........$. I subtracted the 2nd and 1st term and the result was $-\frac{10}{13}$ and then the 3rd and 2nd term and the result was $-\frac{50}{117}$.

Comment: this could theoretically go on with any sets of values. For example, the next one could be $\pi/e$ and the one after $\sqrt{\pi}$. You gotta specify your sequence more precisely.

Comment: Any such sequence will have infinitely many "correct" ways to write a general term. Your calculation shows that it's not an arithmetic progression. If you edit the question to tell us where the terms you have come from perhaps we can help.

Comment: But I found the question in this form only. It was from a set of questions our teacher gave us to do as homework.

Comment: 2nd and 4th terms are the same. is the idea that all even terms are the same and all odd ones form an arithmetic progression?

Comment: Perhaps there's something else useful where you "found the question". If not, then you are probably out of luck.

Comment: sorry, I just edited the question as I saw that fourth term I wrote was different from the question. please see it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple now...

Your sequence is, $\frac{20}{8}, \frac{20}{13}, \frac{20}{18}, \frac{20}{23}, \cdots$

Observe that the denominator is in AP with the common difference of 5.

And clearly, the sequence is in harmonic progression.

Comment: So, the general term is $\frac{20}{5n+3}$

Comment: Yeah! You are correct.

Comment: One moral of the story (besides fixing typos): so called "improper fractions" are much better than "mixed numbers".